# Расширение списка через цикл в функции. Питон

Tags: python, список

```
list1 = []
def func(arg):
        global list1
        for arg in list1:
            if arg not in list1:
                list1.append(arg)
            break
            else:
                continue
```

При запуске func('a') не расширяется список list1

Comment: У Вас форматирование кода съехало, кажется

Comment: И странная конструкция - `for arg in list1:
            if arg not in list1:` - то есть, для каждого `arg` из списка добавление происходит только если его нет в списке, иначе говоря - никогда. По-моему, надо просто убрать `for`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не вижу смысла использовать цикл, если Вы хотите добавить один элемент:

```
def func(arg):
    if arg not in list1:
        list1.append(arg)
        print("append item")
    else:
        print("item already in list")

list1 = [1, 2, 3]

func(1) # item already in list
func(5) # append item
```

Если же хотите передавать в функцию список, тогда можно сделать с циклом:

```
def func(arg):
    for item in arg:
        if item not in list1:
            list1.append(item)
            print("append item")
        else:
            print("item already in list")

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
spam = [1, 2, 5]

func(spam)
# item already in list
# item already in list
# append item
```